# Installing Pytorch on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, anaconda, pytorch

I am trying to install Pytorch on Windows 10 anaconda environment with Python 3.6 using the following command:

```
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch
```

But it gives the following error:

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
>     - curl -> krb5=1.14 -> *[track_features=vc14]
>     - curl -> libssh2=1.8 -> vc==14
>     - pytorch
>   Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

The same goes for the new updated December code

```
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch cuda80
```

Is there a way which will help me install Pytorch on Windows ?

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit computer?

Comment: Yes, I am using a 64-bit OS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the issue by side loading the pytorch's tar.bz2 file

Comment: could you elaborate on how to do that? please?

Comment: Get the required tar file from the following website:
https://anaconda.org/peterjc123/pytorch/files
And then just do:
$ conda install filename.tar.bz2

Answer (score 0):

try to first install with with pip3 (Install pip3 if you don't have it), then do the following command:

pip3 install pytorch

Then repeat the process on conda, also try conda without peterjc123.

Comment: This is wrong as of March 2019. Doing this gives the following exception/error: `Exception: You should install pytorch from http://pytorch.org`

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this command

> > pip3 install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu92/torch-0.4.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl