# How to install pytorch in Anaconda with conda or pip?

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

I am trying to install pytorch in Anaconda to work with Python 3.5 in Windows. Following the instructions in [pytorch.org](http://pytorch.org) I introduced the following code in Anaconda:

```
pip3 install torch torchvision
```

But the following error came in:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\sluis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qmrvz7b9\torch\
```

By searching on the web I found out that it may be because of `setuptools` being out of date but I checked and have it updated. I also tried:

```
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch cuda80
```

But the following error arise:

```
The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - pytorch
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I also tried to load the pytorch's tar.bz2 file which I download in the following website:

[anaconda.org/peterjc123/pytorch/files](http://anaconda.org/peterjc123/pytorch/files)

And then just do:

```
$ conda install filename.tar.bz2
```

But I got the following error:

```
Error: HTTPError: 404 Client Error: None for url: file:///C|/Users/sluis/pytorch-0.3.1-py36_cuda80_cudnn6he774522_2.tar.bz2: file:///C|/Users/sluis/pytorch-0.3.1-py36_cuda80_cudnn6he774522_2.tar.bz2
```

I am quite new to this programming world so I don't really know how to dig more on the errors. Anyone knows how to get pytorch installed?

**Edit:** As suggested in the comments I tried:

```
conda install pytorch torchivsion -c pytorch
```

And I got the following error:

```
Error: Packages missing in current win-64 channels:
 - pytorch
 - torchvision
```

I did:

```
anaconda search -t conda torchvision
```

And tried to install `dericlk/torchvision` using the following command:

```
conda install -c derickl torchvision
```

But I am getting the same error:

```
Error: Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - torchvision
```

I couldn't find any `torchvision`packages for win-64.

`conda list` is giving me the following:

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\aaaa\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\torchenv2:
#
mkl-include               2018.0.2                      1    anaconda
certifi                   2016.2.28                py35_0
cffi                      1.10.0                   py35_0
cmake                     3.6.3                    vc14_0  [vc14]
openmp                    2018.0.0                intel_8    intel
mkl                       2017.0.3                      0
numpy                     1.13.1                   py35_0
pip                       10.0.0                    <pip>
pip                       9.0.1                    py35_1
pycparser                 2.18                     py35_0
python                    3.5.4                         0
pyyaml                    3.12                     py35_0
setuptools                36.4.0                   py35_1
typing                    3.6.2                    py35_0
vc                        14                            0
vs2015_runtime            14.0.25420                    0
wheel                     0.29.0                   py35_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py35_0
zlib                      1.2.11                   vc14_0  [vc14]
```

=======

Comment: I don't use conda, but why are you using pip3 when the pytorch documentation uses conda?
"conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch"
You propably will get the conflict message again so it would be helpful if you could paste the result of the following command
"conda list"

Comment: @pierrom I edited the question so it is both for pip or conda. By Anaconda I meant that it was the prompt I was using. Also I tried what you told me but still it is giving me errors, could you have a look?

Comment: Oh, I assumed you were running on MacOS or Linux because you linked to the pytorch website. Unfortunately, Windows isn't supported yet. I'm sorry that I didn't recognized that before. 
So, it looks like your error is not uncommon. https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/solved-windows-anaconda-pytorch/11080. They are using the same command as you did but without cuda80. But I don't now if it will make a difference. Maybe you can try using pytorch without gpu first. Look here for more info https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/494#issuecomment-351548433

Comment: I ended up running it on Linux and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Answer to similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48675722/installing-pytorch-on-windows-10  worked for me

Answer (score 31):

Go to the official [PyTorch.org](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#start-locally) and follow the steps accordingly.
[image]

Select your preferences and you will see an appropriate command below on the page.

If you don't have GPU in the system, set **CUDA** as **None** or **CPU**

Example command:

```
conda install pytorch-cpu torchvision-cpu -c pytorch
```

Comment: Can the `cpu` version and `gpu` version of pytorch be installed in the same `conda` env?

Comment: yes, you can and in runtime you can switch one of them

Comment: talking of gpu, does it mean nvidia only or even amd and intel?

Comment: Nvidia only as pytorch is utilizing the CUDA library provided by nvidia

Answer (score 27):

The following worked for me. First install `MKL`:

```
conda install -c anaconda mkl
```

After this, install pytorch and torchvision:

```
conda install -c pytorch pytorch torchvision
```

Comment: Make sure to run commands in administrator mode to avoid access denied issues.

Answer (score 4):

For **windows** **python** 3.6 and above without **cuda**

```
pip install torch==1.2.0+cpu torchvision==0.4.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you please try with below steps

1. `conda create -n pytorch_env python=3.5`
2. `source activate pytorch_env`
3. `conda install -c soumith pytorch`
4. `python`

   `> import torch`

You can even find `pytorch` after you execute command `conda list`.

Comment: I think step 2 is meant to use it in Linux rather than in Windows as the command `source` is meant both for Linux and macOS. In any case I ended it up running it on Linux and it worked.

Comment: What does `soumith` signify?

Comment: I was curious and a bit dubious as well until I found https://anaconda.org/soumith/pytorch but more specifically, https://github.com/soumith

Comment: 'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

For linux, cuda9.0, python3.6:

**pip3 install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu90/torch-0.3.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl**

**pip3 install torchvision**

For other cuda/python version: check website: https://ptorch.com/news/145.html

Answer (score 0):

try updating the base conda package with the following command,then you can try reistalling it.

1. conda update --all
2. conda update -n base conda

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked doing this:

Uninstall the previous version: go to C:\users\username\anaconda3 and run the anaconda-uninstall.exe

Install again anaconda

then run the following commands on the anaconda pompt:

conda create -n my_env python=2.7

conda activate my_env

start the gui app

conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch

anaconda-navigator

Answer (score 0):

### For Readers live in 2021/06/xx:

use pip3 install torch

Answer (score 0):

As an update, now the Pytorch official site has the right version depending on your system:

https://pytorch.org/

I recommend using the official website for installation. Some of the previous awnsers may lead to a version that is not adequate.

Answer (score 0):

### After Activating conda environment

Use below command

---

```
python3 -m pip install torch torchvision
```

Example

```
(torchenv) ubuntu@user :~$ python3 -m pip install torch torchvision
```

Answer (score -1):

Visit https://anaconda.org/pytorch/torchvision and you will find the solution

```
conda install -c pytorch torchvision
```

Answer (score -1):

Try running:

```
conda install -c pytorch pytorch
```