# how to install pytorch in python2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytorch, torch

i am using python2.7 in virtual environment. i tried to install pytorch in python2.7 but i got error belows:

```html
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

  - pytorch-cpu -> python[version='3.5.*|3.6.*']
  - pytorch-cpu -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to.  Your current python version
is (python=2.7).  Note that conda will not change your python version to a different minor version
unless you explicitly specify that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package wheel conflicts for:
python=2.7 -> pip -> wheel
pytorch-cpu -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel
Package vc conflicts for:
python=2.7 -> sqlite[version='>=3.27.2,<4.0a0'] -> vc[version='14.*|>=14,<15.0a0|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
python=2.7 -> vc[version='9.*|>=9,<10.0a0']
pytorch-cpu -> numpy[version='>=1.11'] -> vc[version='14|14.*|>=14,<15.0a0']
pytorch-cpu -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0']
Package cffi conflicts for:
pytorch-cpu -> cffi
pytorch-cpu -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> pip -> requests -> urllib3[version='>=1.21.1,<1.25'] -> cryptography[version='>=1.3.4'] -> cffi[version='>=1.7']
python=2.7 -> pip -> requests -> urllib3[version='>=1.21.1,<1.25'] -> cryptography[version='>=1.3.4'] -> cffi[version='>=1.7']
Package pip conflicts for:
python=2.7 -> pip
pytorch-cpu -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> pip
Package setuptools conflicts for:
python=2.7 -> pip -> setuptools
pytorch-cpu -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> pip -> setuptools
Package msgpack-python conflicts for:
python=2.7 -> pip -> cachecontrol -> msgpack-python
pytorch-cpu -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> pip -> cachecontrol -> msgpack-python
```

i tried conda install pytorch-cpu -c pytorch and link(https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/). but it is not worked. so what should i do for install torch in python version2.7? i want to install pytorch cpu version.

plz help:)

Comment: Both for pytorch and and generally for machine learning you would be better off installing python 3 in a virtual environment

Answer (score 2):

Here's the link to the [PyTorch official download page](https://pytorch.org)

From here, you can choose the python version (2.7) and CUDA (None) and other relevant details based on your environment and OS.

Other helpful links:

- [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918479/how-to-install-pytorch-in-anaconda-with-conda-or-pip)
- [windows](https://medium.com/@bryant.kou/how-to-install-pytorch-on-windows-step-by-step-cc4d004adb2a)
- [mac](https://dev.to/berry_clione/install-pytorch-on-mac-by-pip-2fga)
- [ubuntu](https://www.learnopencv.com/installing-deep-learning-frameworks-on-ubuntu-with-cuda-support/)
- [all](https://www.javatpoint.com/pytorch-installation)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that pytorch try to install some packages which requires python >= 3.6 version.

```
Package wheel conflicts for:
python=2.7 -> pip -> wheel
pytorch-cpu -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel
```

You have to specify in command for which python version would you like to install pytorch

Comment: so, you mean i should specify pytorch version for python2.7?

Comment: What os are you using? Note that PyTorch does not support Python 2.7 on Windows.

Comment: I use windows. OMG! can't i use torch in python2.7 on Windows?:(

Answer (score 1):

For me the method in the link https://www.learnopencv.com/installing-deep-learning-frameworks-on-ubuntu-with-cuda-support/
 worked.

This is how I did it:

`!pip install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch-0.2.0.post3-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`

Answer (score 1):

First install conda with python2.7:
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cpuonly -c pytorch

Then activate environment:
conda activate python2

Then install pytorch:
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cpuonly -c pytorch

Check for confirmation:

```
python    
import torch
print(torch._ _version_ _)
```