# I'm unable to install packages like Pytorch,Tensorflow using pip or conda in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, pytorch

I'm unable to install packages like Pytorch,Tensorflow using pip or conda in python on windows10. I already have latest version of Python. I also have strong Internet connection, so internet connection is not an issue. How can I overcome this issue?
"ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrhHV.png)

I watched several YouTube videos and websites still unable to solve the issues. I want a solution.

Comment: Have you already tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49918479/6394617)?

Answer (score 0):

The version of Python you are using is not compatible with PyTorch. PyTorch supports Python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10. and early versions of 3.11.x It is possible that PyTorch does not yet support Python 3.11.4

You can read this at their official github:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/86566

[image]

I would suggest you to downgrade to version 3.10 so you can use stable versions of pytorch.

Comment: Is python 3.11 not compatible for tensorflow also?

Comment: In the snipped that you show, there is only torch, so i have only looked at the dependencies that you show. Can you please run pip3 istall for tensorflow only?